# MVVM, Devo usar ICommand em todos os controles?

Tags: c#, mvvm

Faz parte do MVVM o uso de `commands` através da interface `ICommand`. A pergunta é, devo usar `commands` em todos os controles? Mesmo aqueles que não estão ligados com a regra de negócios?
Por exemplo, um `HambugerButton` cuja única finalidade é expandir ou recolher um `HambugerMenu`. Devo aplicar `Command` nele também?

Comment: Se a acção do botão for apenas relacionada com a view, não vejo qualquer  problema em que seja feita no *code behind*.

Comment: Se for só você que vai mexer no código é até aceitável, o problema é quando muita gente trabalha no mesmo código aí a bagunça tá feita, mostrar um determinado componente pra mim pode fazer parte da regra de negócio, já para outro desenvolvedor não.

Comment: Você não precisa usar em todos os controles. O ICommand abstrai uma ação dentro da sua ViewModel. E pelo fato da viewmodel não conhecer a View você não deve atrelar essas ações com, por exemplo, a abertura e fechamento do HambugerMenu. Esse tipo de regra fica a cargo da View.

Comment: Seja consistente, se já usa `ICommands` para os outros comandos continue a usá-los. Um outro programador encontrará os comandos todos no mesmo lugar e isso é bom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, minha opinião é que você deva usar `Commands` em todas as situações, pois mantém a consistência do padrão `MVVM` e não causa confusão, pois misturar `code-behind` com `MVVM` vai causar dor de cabeça em quem for mexer no seu código pois as funcionalidades estarão misturadas em partes diferentes do código.

Por exemplo, olhe como uma implementação `MVVM` fica limpa e direta:

Usando o exemplo de abrir um controle através de um botão.

```
// XAML - HamburgerMenu
<controls:HamburgerMenu IsOpen={binding MenuIsOpen} />
```

A propriedade booleana `IsOpen` do `HambugerMenu` foi ligada a uma propriedade também booleana da minha view-model chamada `MenuIsOpen`.

```
// View-Model
public bool MenuIsOpen { get; private set; } // Implementar INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Você tem o botão que expande (abre) o `HamburgerMenu`.

```
 // XAML - Button
 <controls:Button Command={binding OpenMenu} />
```

O comando do botão foi ligado ao `ICommand` da minha view-model chamado `OpenMenu`.

```
// View-Model
public ICommand OpenMenu = new RelayCommand(OpenMenuCommand);

private void OpenMenuCommand()
{
   MenuIsOpen = !MenuIsOpen; // Alterna entre aberto e fechado.
}
```

Pronto, deste modo você alterna entre aberto e fechado seu HamburgerMenu, sem eventos, sem code-behind, sem código surpresa.

No exemplo acima, qualquer método dentro da sua view-model pode controlar a abertura e fechamento do seu `hamburgerMenu` através da propriedade `MenuIsOpen` o que é muito bom para a reutilização de código pois caso surja alguma rotina em que você precise controlar a abertura do controle, ele já está disponível para você, o que não seria possível com code-behind (não de um jeito limpo), então assim você continua no padrão `MVVM`, tem um código limpo, a sua view contém apenas os `bindings`, a view-model nem sabe da existência dos controles.

Comment: As pessoas sempre comentam o que deve ser usado, mas você foi um passo além e explicou os motivos práticos de se utilizar. Resposta de alto nível.